# What is the difference between .next & .getNext() in java?

Tags: java, linked-list

I'm writing pseudocode for an algorithm to swap nodes in a linked list and had a quick question: is there a difference between .next &.getNext()?

One is a method I know but I was wondering if these are identical:

And if they aren't, could you explain why one would be more efficient than the other? Thank you!

```
Algorithm swap(x, y):
Node n <-- head
while( n.getNext() != x ) do
    n <-- n.getNext()
Node v <-- y.getNext()
n.setNext(y)
y.setNext(x)
x.setNext(v)

----------------------

Algorithm swap(x, y):
Node n <-- head
while( n.next != x ) do
    n <-- n.next
Node v <-- y.next
n.setNext(y)
y.setNext(x)
x.setNext(v)
```

Comment: What is `Algorithm` and `Node`? This looks like pseudocode, with `next` being a field for the next node and `get/setNext` being a getter/setter.

Comment: Are you asking about the difference between field access and a getter method?

Comment: None of the methods you are referring to exist in LinkedList

Comment: As this is pseudo-code, the details of accessing a "next" member or calling a "getNext" function shouldn't matter as you're trying to express the intent of your code and not the details of the fine implementation. Also, as you're trying to swap to linked list, you could simply swap the "head", and not each element individually.

Comment: @Mr_Hic-up thank you. Can you elaborate on what you mean by swapping the head? What if I had a list of, say 50 elements, and wanted to swap 2 random elements?

Comment: Ok my bad, I thought you wanted to swap the whole list. A closer look seems to indicate that you want to swap 2 values inside the same list. However, the rest of the pseudo-code doesn't really make sense to me then. But that's not the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Perhaps you mean what is the difference between accessing a field `next` directly, and accessing a field indirectly using an accessor method `getNext()`, is that it?

Accessing directly by name is more efficient in theory, as it is the most direct way to access data in an object. But it violates encapsulation, because the field of a class should be hidden implementation details. You also cannot separate read/write access, as the access modifiers are not granular enough.

Accessing using an accessory method is good encapsulation. It gives you the freedom to mess with the implementation details, for example store the next node in a file instead of memory, without affecting users of the class. You can also extend the class, and override the logic with something specialized for a purpose.

Since encapsulation is so important in object oriented programming, direct access to fields is strongly discouraged, and using accessor methods is the preferred approach.

Comment: Thank you @janos, well put.